# jsPDF not taking svg as DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, rendering, jspdf

I am using jsPDF in React js. I am crating some content and drawings inside a <svg>. When I want to render the pdf, everything inside the SVG is not rendered. Is there any solution to solve this or another one to export the SVG to pdf? I want the text inside the pdf to be selectable as well, I don't want just to transform the SVG into a picture and drop it into a pdf, that is not a solution. Below is my code that is not working

```
import React from 'react'
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
const About = () => {

const downloadPDF = () => {
        let doc = new jsPDF("p","pt","a4")
        doc.html(document.querySelector("#graph"), {
            callback: function(pdf){
                pdf.save("doc.pdf");
            }
        })
    }
 return (
         <div id = "graph">
            Some text // {/*This is rendered */}
            <h1>some title</h1> {/*This is rendered */}
            <svg  width="500" height="500"> {/*This is not rendered */}
                <circle cx="50" cy="80" r={radius} stroke="rgb(0,125,225)" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
            </svg>
         </div>
  )
}

export default About
```